# MVC3 Script function placing - strange behaviour

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, jquery-ui-dialog

Here is the scenario:

**I.** A button is clicked.

**II.** The binder `jQuery(document).on("click",buttonSelector,callback)`, primarly:

- Creates a `<div id="popup-wrapper"></div>` element
- Loads the **href** from the *button*, into this ↑ div.

AND FINNALY, as a callback

**Initialize the dialog with**

```
jQuery("#popup-wrapper").dialog({
         title: "Sample Title",
         close: function () {
                    jQuery("#wizard").steps("destroy"); // plugin's method
                    // or even jQuery("#wizard").remove() via jQuery
                    jQuery(this).dialog("destroy").remove(); 
                },
         modal: true,
         width: 'auto',
         height: 'auto'
});
```

**III.** Inside the newly Opened UI Dialog we have a **Wizard plugin** called [jQuery Steps](http://jquery-steps.com). Here is the **Partial View** :

```
    @{
       Layout=null;
     }
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/System/jQuery-steps/jquery.steps.css")">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/System/jQuery-steps/jquery.steps.js")"></script>

    <div id="wizard">
        <h3>First step</h3>
        <section class="step-content">
            //other code
            <input type="text" id="datepicker-obj"> // Another partial with jQuery(doc).ready .... initialize datepicker()
        </section>
    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function () {
       jQuery("#wizard").steps({
            headerTag: "h1",
            bodyTag: "section",
            transitionEffect: "slideLeft",
            stepsOrientation: "vertical"
        });
      });
    </script>
```

**IV.** Everything works excellent. The `steps` plugin is initialized, and the `datepicker` works well.

**V.** I close the UI Dialog Window.

**VI.** The `close: function(){.... }` is called and then
        1. The `Steps() object` is destroyed.
        2. Dialog is `destroyed` and `removed`.

**VII.** I click *again* the button and the steps from **I-III** are repeated

## THE PROBLEM

1.After the second UI Dialog call all the inner plugins inside the `steps` wizard, do not work properly. Eg: the datepicker doesn't show-up.

### Temporary solution

If I change the script, to be upper than the `<div id="wizard"></div>`, like this way:

```
   <script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function () {
       jQuery("#wizard").steps({
            headerTag: "h1",
            bodyTag: "section",
            transitionEffect: "slideLeft",
            stepsOrientation: "vertical"
        });
      });
    </script>

    <div id="wizard">...</div>
```

then **Everything works very nice**

## The QUESTION

What is the explanation of such a result? Why the script function positioning matters in this case?

THANK YOU

Comment: Do you get the same behavior in other browsers too?

Comment: Yes, Tested on Opera, Chrome, Firefox